# How to reload css settings when ng-show hide some items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

A selection on page and are used to filter the items in a table.
the table displays like this:
[image]

Here we can see the item's color is gray-dark every other row.
if I modify some of them(I modified two gray items):
[image]

and using the selection to show the modified ones:
[image]

the rows of the table are all gray, not gray-dark...
I guess this is because ng-show hides the other rows but not reload the css(I use ng-class-odd to draw the table rows color)
Are there any good ideas to let the filtered items displays gray-dark every other row?

Comment: How did you implement this filter? If you remove DOM elements instead of hiding them, you would have your checkered rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-if instead of ng-show.
Then the rows won't be included in the DOM, and the CSS selector of odd/even will work.